# Obtaining a Unit Where I Should Be Obtaining an Integer

Tags: f#

I have been trying to write a recursive function which takes a certain number as an input and outputs the sum of all the numbers that are multiples of 3 and 5 from 1 to the input number (3 + 5 + 9..n).

Here is my code

```
let rec add_nums n = 
    if n < 1 then 0
    if (n%5 > 0) then 0
    else n + add_nums(n-1)
```

Comment: Your first `if` lacks an `else`. Should the second `if` be an `elif` maybe?

Comment: I never realized that F# had an `elif`! If I need more than one branch, I usually switched from an `if` to a `match`. Thanks for the comment, @TeaDrivenDev: I learned something new.

Answer (score 7):

`if`'s are expressions in F# rather than statements. Since they're expressions, both `then` and `else` branches need to have the same return type. What this means in practice is that you cannot have an `if` without an `else` branch **unless** `then` branch returns a unit (which allows the `else` branch to be omitted). The compiler sees that `else` was omitted, and infers that the type of `then` branch should have been `unit`.

This fixes it:

```
let rec add_nums n = 
    if n < 1 
        then 0
        else if (n%5 > 0) 
                 then 0
                 else n + add_nums(n-1)
```

If you format your `if`'s that way, it will make catching such problems easier.

And arguably you could also put both your predicates in a single `if`.

Comment: That formatting looks absurd to me; personally, I would red-flag any code checkin that looks like that. BTW `elif` is a single token, no need for `else if`.

Comment: Having `then` and `else` indented in separate lines is "absurd" to you? Curious.

Comment: (IMO) The rapid growth rightwards is absurd because A) it doesn't scale for a long `elif` chain and B) deep indentation generally implies deep nested scope, which does not exist here.

Comment: A) there's no `elif` here and B) those are nested scopes. But I see what you mean. I'm not trying to suggest this is how you should write production code. If you have a single binary choice, use `if`, if you have multiple predicates, use `match`. `elif` doesn't have a real home in F#.

Comment: The point of this snippet however is to illustrate a particular property of how `if` expressions work in F#. Saying "use elif" or "use match" is suggesting a workaround rather than explaining that property.

Answer (score 6):

May I boldly suggest using a match?

```
let rec add_nums n = 
    match n with
    | x when x < 1 -> 0
    | x when x % 5 > 0 -> 0
    | _ -> n + add_nums(n-1)
```

Adding more conditions then is somewhat "easier" and (can be)  more readable...

Using match is also "better" in the regard that it will (possibly) make it easier to see errors in return value.